# Inconsistent reputation detail (by post vs by time)

Tags: support, feature-request, status-bydesign

Reputation may be viewed "by post" or "by time" (or "graph"): [image]

When viewing the reputation "by post", multiple activity per post is expandable:

[image: Reputation view by post]

However, this is not the case when viewing reputation "by time":

[image: Reputation view by time]

Why is this? I would think the format is easy to manage since the hook is on the post, which makes grouping an intuitive option. However, what do you group under when it comes to time? Has there been some consideration to accommodate some time-wise grouping? Or perhaps just leaving the reputation expanded?

Comment: Note that this is the same for all stackexchange sites and the TeX.SX moderators don't have direct influence on that or most other site styles. There is also a general meta site http://meta.stackexchange.com/, which I personally would post such feature-requests to. But it is fine to first post it here.

Comment: @Martin We look at all sites - no need to raise it on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Grace: I know that you look at all sites, but it would get better attention from other users at the main meta site. This isn't TeX.SX specific after all.

Comment: @Martin The only people this needs to be seen by are the people in charge of fixing it. You get equal attention here as over there. The only thing posting on Meta Stack Overflow would do is expose it to a whole bunch of people who can't do anything, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to a question of "**how valuable is this info?**" vs. "**how much noise does it add?**".

In this case, it adds more noise than value.  We show the latest date *of that string of events*, e.g. "upvotes on post X".  How much does it matter *exactly when each vote happened*? Not that much 99% of the time, so we went for simple - it's an intentional design choice for the chronological view.